# Donut going under plane

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]

Following blender guru tutorial part 6, timestamp 10:15 he adds a plane, however unlike mine his sticks under the donut right away. I probably messed up along the way, but i don't know where exactly.

Comment: A new object will appear where you've put the 3D cursor, so maybe you've moved the 3D cursor, or the donut. To put the plane at the center, select it and press Alt G

Answer (score 0):

You can use face snapping to have an object "stick" to another one when moving it.

[image: magnet icon representing snapping]

Just click on the magnet icon and select the square (face) on the dropdown next to it.